# Parte de la clave es erronea. Una parte de la clave no es una cadena o la longitud usada es tan grande como la parte de la clave

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a la base de datos pero me da error y ya no se que pueda ser.

Se las comparto:

```
CREATE TABLE `escu_26753659_controlmrva`.`usertbl` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_name` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`(11)),
  UNIQUE (`username`(20))
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Sin embargo el servidor responde

> "#1089 - Parte de la clave es errónea. Una parte de la clave no es una
> cadena o la longitud usada es tan grande como la parte de la clave"

Ya no se que hacer, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Deberías agregar tu consulta y describir mejor que tratas de obtener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que quieres utilizar el campo `username` como único, pero le estás diciendo a UNIQUE que utilice solo una parte `(20)`. Que esta parte sea igual que la longitud del campo puede ser lo que cause el error. Pasa algo similar con la clave primaria 'id(11)'. Podrías solucionarlo así:

```
CREATE TABLE `escu_26753659_controlmrva`.`usertbl` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_name` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE (`username`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```